Failing to set up username and password in "appears" package in R
I am trying to extract "MODIS" data using "AppEARS" package in R. Before doing that it requires me to set username and password in the following way:
rs_set_key(user = "prwoc_ec",
+            password = "XXXXXXXXXXXXX")

Error in b_wincred_i_get(target) : 
  Windows credential store error in 'get': Element not found.

But doing exactly as package requires I get the error given above. I tried manually setting up the credentials but that also didn't work. Can someone suggest me how should I proceed?

I think this should be "appeears" (two "e"s, and all lower case) for the R package name

Searching for the error message gets me here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451952/error-when-using-r-to-get-credentials-from-windows-cred-vault which makes me think this is a Windows problem with keyring handling, and a possible solution is in the responses there (dated Feb 12, so fairly recent).

Yes, I already followed what he suggested but the problem persist.
